# How to diff docx files with git difftool

Tags: git, diff, git-difftool

Whereas it is not so difficult, to get docx files diffed through

```
git diff xxx.docx
```

i did not find a way to do so using `git difftool` 
which would be quite convenient. 
To recall configuration for diff:

- in gitattributes place a line `*.docx diff=word`, where `word` is just a placeholder
- in gitconfig place

```
[diff "word"]
  textconv = astextplain
```

Here, `asplaintext` is some converter converting .docx into plain text.

If i call `git difftool xxx.docx` these tools seem not to be applied. 
I would expect that the difftool is invoked with output of `asplaintext`, but it is not.

Am I too stupid to find a way, or is this just a gap in git?? 
That feature would be very nice because i use `gitahead` which invokes, 
as many other gui backends `git difftool`.

Comment: `.docx` files are zip files, binaries, you can't compare them as text and get any meaningful data.

Comment: You could try: https://github.com/vigente/gerardus/wiki/Integrate-git-diffs-with-word-docx-files

Comment: What @Philippe said! I use that too. pandoc is required, for me it just happens that I already used pandoc to begin with. To sum up what you are going do: add a new diff command that converts docx to markdown, tell repo to use new diff for docx-files. You might want to tweet the pandoc command a bit and add the command parameter 'preserve line' or something like that. Works like a charm

Comment: @blindy, i know. But still there are ways to do so if filtering those files accordingly. See the git manual.